# Storing attributes for a single element over multiple object property fields

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

Is it considered bad practice to spread attributes that will be applied to a single element over multiple arrays inside of multiple object properties.
Such as

```
var properties={};
properties.name=['fish','car','plane','boat', UP TO 1000];
properties.color=['blue','green','yellow','magenta','etc'];
properties.link=['link1','link2','link3','etc'];
properties.date=[,,,,,];   
properties.XY=[,,,,,];   
properties.subject=[,,,,,];   
properties.createdBy=[,,,,,];   

Element.name=properties.name[1];
Element.color=properties.color[1];
Element.link=properties.link[1];
Element.onclick=properties.date[1];
```

I was initially using arrays embedded in functions, or closures but have gotten a lot of negative feedback.  Also not interested in using a library as of yet.  Trying to stick with vanilla.js for now.

Comment: Can you give a more concrete example?

Comment: What specific problem are you trying to solve? As it is, without context, this almost definitively opinion based, and therefore off-topic.

Comment: I agree that it is unclear what problem you are solving.  The thing that looks odd to me is having these numerically indexed arrays of seemingly unrelated terms.  How would one use them in an application context?  HOw would one know that `properties.A[2]` contains `plane`?  I don't see a meaningful key-value or indexing system here.

Comment: `var Elements = [{name:'fish',color:'blue'...}, {name:'car',color:'green'...}];`?

Comment: Yes that would be bad practice, mainly because that both does not scale well at all and is confusing when read by someone not familiar with it.

Comment: The property names I am using are more descriptive than A,B,C.  I was only attempting to show you the pattern of storing the data.

Comment: I voted to close the question. What you are doing is just fine, but whether it is the best approach depends a lot on the specific context. In this respect @Barmar's answer is opinion based.

Comment: @Christophe It might be opinion based, but from the time I spent here, I must say that every question that gets an answer from Barmar is constructive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of having each property in a separate array, make an array of objects:

```
var properties = [
    { name: 'fish',
      color: 'blue',
      link: 'link1'
    },
    { name: 'car',
      color: 'green',
      link: 'link2'
    }
    ...
];
```

Then you can just access `Element = properties[i]` and it will have all the properties you want in one place.

To avoid having to repeat all the property names, you can write a function:

```
function makeProp (name, color, link) {
    return { name: name, color: color, link: link };
}
```

Then your array looks like:

```
var properties = [
    makeProp('fish', 'blue', 'link1'),
    makeProp('car', 'green', 'link2'),
    ...
];
```

Comment: Sorry to repeat what I wrote below, but for 1000+ elements?  That seems like a lot of repetitive code.

Comment: No matter how you arrange it, you'll have to write all 1,000 elements somewhere. Either a bunch of arrays that each have 1,000 elements, or an array of 1,000 objects.

Comment: If you do it as separate arrays, you need to make sure that they're all kept in sync. If you skip an element in one of the arrays, everything after that will be wrong.

Comment: Just seems like a lot of useless code repeating "name", "color", "etc"---over writing property.name just once.  I also thought this might be faster if i needed to sort through same property for all elements.

Comment: Didn't you see my update that shows how to avoid having to repeat them?

Comment: Are you really creating all of this literally in the code, versus getting it from an API or database?

Comment: @rancho There is a reason why we use `element.style.color = 'red'` instead of `element[10][2] = 'red'` to style an element in javascript, because it makes more sense when you read it, and it is easier to debug.

Comment: Sorry about all the confusion with the example I used.  I was merely trying to give an example of data storage pattern.  Not which properties I am storing.  The properties I am storing are  coordinates, file locations, and other pieces of data. I am trying to put as much data as possible into an html file that will be loaded into iframe and processed by the main page.

Comment: The bgeneral idea is to try to keep related data together. Your way of doing it was common in the days of BASIC and FORTRAN, which didn't have structured data objects. But in modern programming languages, that's unnecessary and confusing.

Comment: Did no one see that I accepted Barmars answer?

Comment: I don't see a check mark